# read PHP string as integer

Tags: php

This may seem like a rudimentary question, that I'm sure has been answered elsewhere. But, as I can't find the answer, I hope someone can help.

I have a variable: `$_POST['totalrevenue']` that was passed from a PHP page (home.php) through ajax to another PHP page (ajax.php).

The value is 2,900 and should be read as an integer, but is read as a string on ajax.php.

Doing

```
settype($_POST['totalrevenue'], int)
```

converts the string to an integer with the new value of `2`.

What is the best way to convert this string into an integer while retaining the initial value (2,900) in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Comment: `"2,900"` could be interpreted as either `2900` or `2.9` depending on your locale settings. I would suggest that you simply not accept characters other than digits and [optionally] whatever the current locale's representation of a decimal is.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that "2,900" is *not* a number - it is a string. That comma ruins all the magic.

Transform the comma to a dot, and now (float) and floatval(), or intval(), will process it correctly:

```
$value = (float)str_replace(',', '.', $oldValue);
```

Or if the ',' is a thousands separator (I can't tell it either), replace it with an empty string. '2,900' becomes 2900 and that's all you need:

```
$value = (int)str_replace(',', '', $oldValue);
```

(On re-reading your question, you're in the latter scenario. The above is still true for "floating point" strings).

Comment: *screams internally for not realizing the mistake* thank you. +1 this worked.

Comment: If it can lessen the pain, I make this mistake more or less *every time* I import or export something from a Microsoft Excel file. Usually before the UTF8 mistakes, and almost always before the rounding mistakes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the (int) or (float) to cast the type before the variable.

```
$var = (int)str_replace(',', '.', $prevVar); /* for float */
```

and

```
$var = (float)str_replace(',', '.', $prevVar); /* for int */
```